# Gradle Build Cache after gradle clean

Tags: caching, gradle

According to [Built-in cacheable tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html#sec:task_output_caching_cacheable_tasks) the gradle task "test" supports build caching. I wonder how the build cache works, if I run `gradle clean` between 2 `gradle test` executions. Since `gradle clean` deletes the test results (assuming these are parts of the output of `gradle test` in the build cache context), the cache won't work here. Is that correct?

Some background:
We've got a multi-project setup in gradle and would like to skip tests in subprojects, when there were no changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build cache does not store the task outputs in the project workspace, but in a local or remote build cache. The local build cache lives in the Gradle user home.

So the cache will work, even if you run `clean`, since the outputs of the `test` task are stored in the build cache and are not removed from there by running `clean`.